# TestContainer cannot find the docker daemon lima

Tags: java, docker, testcontainers, nerdctl

I am running a lima default container as shown below

```
limactl start default.yml
```

And if I run `docker run hello-world`, it works correctly. I see that docker host which this daemon connects is `unix\:///Users/user/.lima/docker/sock/docker.sock`

So I configured Testcontainer property file as below

```
docker.client.strategy=org.testcontainers.dockerclient.EnvironmentAndSystemPropertyClientProviderStrategy
docker.host=unix\:///Users/user/.lima/docker/sock/docker.sock
```

When I run the testcontainer , it fails with below status

````
04:12:12.095 [testcontainers-ryuk] DEBUG org.testcontainers.utility.ResourceReaper - Sending 'label=org.testcontainers%3Dtrue&label=org.testcontainers.sessionId%3Df9821c44-4de0-44d4-89e5-634d050676a1' to Ryuk
04:12:12.101 [testcontainers-ryuk] DEBUG org.testcontainers.utility.ResourceReaper - Didn't receive 'ACK' from Ryuk. Will retry to send filters.
.............
.............```

And fails. 

How to make the Testcontainer to run on new docker environment created by Lima. Am I doing the configuration correctly?
````

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the docker socket to get your setup running:

```
DOCKER_HOST=unix:///Users/your-user/.lima/docker/sock/docker.sock
TESTCONTAINERS_DOCKER_SOCKET_OVERRIDE=/var/run/docker.sock
```